# Unable to receive booking request email from website

Tags: joomla

Since I migrated hosting from host gator to hostinger I am unable to receive booking request emails(apart from yahoo mail account) from my website’s online reservation page. I asked their technical support to fix it but they said I need to configure inside Joomla and they are unable to fix it. I don’t know how to fix this. Help please.

Hosting provider tried every method but unable to fix. Need assistance to configure inside Joomla please.